# How to process potentially async aggregate tasks in parallel and process them as each task completes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parallel-processing, async-await

I've got myself into a situation that, in "normal" c# land would probably be relatively easy to solve, but is a bit more complex with the caveats of Unity.

The high level is I've got a set of tasks that need to run, some of which can be in parallel, and some of which are async, others not. For those that can be run in parallel, as each task completes I need to fire off an event (in the main thread) to let any interested parties know that a task was completed.

To dig into the specifics, this is for a game in Unity, however this particular code has a requirement that it can't touch the Unity API as it's going to be in a separate project that is pure c#.

Conceptually in my game, I have a "Day Transition". Each night when the player goes to bed (or passes out from exhaustion/gets knocked out by enemies) the game will go to a loading screen to process longer running operations that I wouldn't want to do in the middle of gameplay. Things such as running the simulation to update the daily economy, or file I/O to load in things to be used during the next day.

These takes may or may not be thread safe, and may or may not actually be true async calls (file loads will be, for example).

My goal is to do this in a way that blocks the main thread as little as possible (some blocking is going to happen, it's unavoidable since some tasks may touch the Unity API which is required to happen on the main thread. Those aren't thread safe).

Because some things will be async, I treat everything as awaitable.

My DayTransitioner class has a list of IDayTransitionAction objects:

```
public interface IDayTransitionAction
{
    bool IsRepeating { get; }
    bool IsThreadSafe { get; }
    Task ProcessTransitionAsync();
}
```

There are really two distinct processes that need to happen here.

The first is that code that is threadsafe (async or not) needs to be able to be kicked off in a way where they can actually run in parallel, and as they complete an event needs to fire off on the main thread.

```
protected async Task ProcessThreadSafeTasks()
{
    //1st kick off in parallel, probably using one of the Task 
    //methods such as WhenAll or WhenAny or some other voodoo...
    //Not really sure what API calls or structure to use to do it...

    //As each comes back an event needs to be fired. 
    //The event needs to occur on the main thread.
    //this.OnIndividualItemProcessed();
}
```

The second is that the things that aren't thread safe need to get run and awaited on (I understand that the synchronous process in this group will block the main thread, but when one is truly async it shouldn't).

The second case is actually the easiest to resolve because Unity provides a synchronization context that forces execution on the main thread. So the latter, I think, can simply await in a loop.

```
protected async Task ProcessNonThreadSafeTasks()
{
    foreach (var actionItem in this.nonThreadSafeActions)
    {
        await actionItem.ProcessTransitionAsync();

        //Raise the OnIndividualItemProcessed event so eventually
        //a loading bar can be filled in as tasks complete, though
        //this class doesn't know or care about the loading bar
        //specifically. Just that interested parties want to know
        //when an individual task is completed
        this.OnIndividualItemProcessed();
    }
}
```

It's that pesky first case that's giving me a headache as I'm not really sure how to kick them off in a way that allows them to be run in parallel while also sending out an event as each individual one completes (especially given Unity's sync context...I assume I have to temporarily override that somehow). How would I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance!

Also, for reference the method that will call both of the above...

```
public async Task ProcessTransitionActions()
{
    //Used primarily to lock down the lists while processing is ongoing.
    //The Add method will dump anything that's attempting to be stored
    //to another list to be sorted and added to the main lists after processing
    //is finished.
    IsProcessing = true;

    await this.ProcessThreadSafeTasks();
    await this.ProcessNonThreadSafeTasks();

    //Purge any actions that aren't repeating.
    this.CleanNonRepeatingActions();
    //Add any actions that were stored while processing to the main lists.
    this.SortStoredActions();

    IsProcessing = false;

    //Send out an event to allow interested parties to know processing is
    //finished.
    this.OnProcessingCompleted();
}
```

**Edit 1***

Just to clarify, the "thread-safe" operations are intended to be run (or at least be capable of being run) on other threads (true-parallel) as opposed to simply concurrently on the main thread. It's when they're completed and I need to shoot out the event that that event specifically needs to go out on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not really sure how to kick them off in a way that allows them to be run in parallel while also sending out an event as each individual one completes

The easiest way to solve this is to introduce a new `async` method. It's way easier to introduce a new `async` method than to try to build a collection and process them as they complete by adding a new action to them. Instead, you want to first *compose* the action item and the event raising, and *then* do them concurrently. (It's "concurrent", not "parallel", since we're only using one thread).

The new `async` method, a composition of the two:

```
private async Task ProcessActionAndRaiseEvent(ActionItem actionItem)
{
  await actionItem.ProcessTransitionAsync();
  this.OnIndividualItemProcessed();  
}
```

Then you can run them concurrently:

```
protected async Task ProcessNonThreadSafeTasks()
{
  var tasks = this.nonThreadSafeActions.Select(ProcessActionAndRaiseEvent).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The `Select(..).ToList` will start all the tasks. However, the synchronous tasks *will* block, which may delay starting some of the truly asynchronous tasks. You might want to add a designator for "truly asynchronous" tasks and sort them first in your `nonThreadSafeActions` collection. That way, all the asynchronous tasks will start, followed by the blocking tasks.

If you want to run the (possibly blocking) transition logic on thread pool threads, you can do some easy parallelization by invoking them with `Task.Run`:

```
private async Task ProcessActionAndRaiseEvent(ActionItem actionItem)
{
  await Task.Run(() => actionItem.ProcessTransitionAsync());
  this.OnIndividualItemProcessed();  
}
```

These then compose the same way as the previous example (using `Task.WhenAll`).

Comment: I actually want parallel (multiple-threads), not just concurrent operation, for the thread safe operations.

Comment: I'm wondering if, in the composed method you suggested, I were to instead do await Task.Run(() => actionItem.ProcessTransitionAsync()) if that would send them off to the threadpool, while executing the event when the task completes on the main thread.

The issue then is would that guarantee they run on a thread other than the main thread or not...

Comment: @TylerW: Sorry, I interpreted by your question (and the variable name `nonThreadSafeActions`) that these actions *did* require the main thread, and you just wanted the truly asynchronous ones to run concurrently. If you have all thread-safe actions, then you can just change the one line as you propose: `await actionItem.ProcessTransitionAsync();` becomes `await Task.Run(() => actionItem.ProcessTransitionAsync());`. `Task.Run` guarantees that the transitions run on a thread pool thread, and `OnIndividualItemProcessed` will run on the UI thread.

Comment: Heh yeah, I'm actually doing both. I have one list in there of thread safe operations, and one of non-thread safe operations.

With the non-thread safe ones I don't care about concurrency because I know it's a mix of async and non-async code. It'll block till it gets to a truly async method no matter what.

I might want to sort them so that there's a truly async operation every so often instead of just add order (so the UI animations can move), but that's a thing I'll do once I measure performance.

Comment: But side note, when you have time can you edit the answer to point to the comments and then I can mark it as the accepted answer (just want to make sure people that end up searching see the comments parts about task.run() to do it in parallel)

Comment: @TylerW: Done.​

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this.

Not particularly efficient if you have thousands of them, but if you have a few dozen should work fine.

```
class TransitionRunner
{
    readonly List<IDayTransitionAction> list = new List<IDayTransitionAction>();
    readonly HashSet<Task> runningTasks = new HashSet<Task>();

    public async Task runAll()
    {
        Debug.Assert( 0 == runningTasks.Count );

        foreach( var dta in list )
        {
            if( dta.IsThreadSafe )
            {
                // Thread safe tasks are started and finished on the thread pool's threads
                Func<Task> fnRun = dta.ProcessTransitionAsync;
                runningTasks.Add( Task.Run( fnRun ) );
            }
            else
            {
                // Non-thread safe tasks are started and finished on the GUI thread.
                // If they're not actually async, the following line will run the complete task.
                Task task  = dta.ProcessTransitionAsync();
                if( task.IsCompleted )
                {
                    // It was a blocking task without await
                    // Or maybe await that completed extremely fast.
                    if( task.IsCompletedSuccessfully )
                        OnIndividualItemProcessed();
                    else
                        await task; // Propagate exception
                }
                else
                    runningTasks.Add( task );
            }
        }

        while( runningTasks.Count > 0 )
        {
            runningTasks.Remove( await Task.WhenAny( runningTasks ) );
            OnIndividualItemProcessed();
        }
    }
}
```